# JavaScript prototype scope issue

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I'm new to JavaScript so I apologize if it's too dumb question.I don't understand how `this` keyword behaves in examples below.

In first case, `this` refers to `window` object:

```
Element.prototype.x = this;
some_element.x; // Returns window object.
```

And in second, it refers to DOM Element:

```
Element.prototype.x = function(){return this;};
some_element.x(); // Returns element itself.
```

Why? How do those examples differ?

Comment: this should help https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work/3127440#3127440

Comment: next time publish the full source.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, this refers to window object:

`Element.prototype.x = this;` ( Here the scope points to window "Global scope in js" )

And in second, it refers to DOM Element:

`Element.prototype.x = function(){return this;};` ( But where as here You are defining a function to the Object "Element", so the scope of this keyword is pointing "Element" Object. )